# Z-Index not showing element ontop of other elements

Tags: css, html, z-index

`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <title> Anime Vortex - Home </title>
 <style>
  body
  {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: "Merienda One", cursive;
   background-image: url(madara.png);
  }
  .topnav 
  {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #553;
  }
  .topnav a 
  {
   float: left;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 20px;
  }
  .topnav-right a:hover
  {
     background-color: #0fe0dc;
     color: black;
  }
  .topnav a.active 
  {
     background-color: #01c19e;
     color: white;
  }
  .topnav-centered img
  {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     height: 90%;
  }
  .topnav-right
  {
     float: right;
  }
  .dropdown 
  {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dropdown .dropbtn
  {
      font-size: 20px;    
      border: none;
      outline: none;
       color: white;
       padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
  }
  .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn
  {
      background-color: #01c19e;
  }
  .dropdown-content 
  {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
  }
  .dropdown-content a
  {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .dropdown-content a:hover 
  {
      background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
  {
      display: block;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px)
  {
     .topnav a, .topnav-right
     {
       float: none;
       display: block;
     }
     .topnav-centered a
     {
       position: relative;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       transform: none;
     }
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One" rel = "stylesheet">
 <div class = "topnav">
    <div class = "topnav-centered">
      <img src = "AV.png">
    </div>
    <a href = "#home" class = "active"> <i class = "fa fa-fw fa-home"> </i> Home </a>
    <div class = "dropdown">
     <button class = "dropbtn"> Genre 
      <i class = "fa fa-caret-down"> </i> 
     </button>
      <div class = "dropdown-content">
         <a href = "#"> Cars </a>
         <a href = "#"> Shounen </a>
         <a href = "#"> Sports </a>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class = "topnav-right">
      <a href = "#createaccount"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"> </i> Create Account </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`I am trying to create a dropdown menu for my website,changing z-index is not bringing the dropdown infront of other elements.

[The image looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IahLF.png)

If you want me to include the CSS, ill include.. If there is any quick fix let me know. Z-index and changing position: absolute doesn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, could you please add your code snippets so that people can help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `overflow:hidden` you have in place meaning that dropdown was there but the overflow was hiding it.

I'm assuming the overflow was there as a clearfix? If so, alternative solutions exist.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <title> Anime Vortex - Home </title>
 <style>
  body
  {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: "Merienda One", cursive;
   background-image: url(madara.png);
  }
  .topnav 
  {
   position: relative;
   /* overflow: hidden; */ /* remove this */
   background-color: #553;
  }
  .topnav a 
  {
   float: left;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 20px;
  }
  .topnav-right a:hover
  {
     background-color: #0fe0dc;
     color: black;
  }
  .topnav a.active 
  {
     background-color: #01c19e;
     color: white;
  }
  .topnav-centered img
  {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     height: 90%;
  }
  .topnav-right
  {
     float: right;
  }
  .dropdown 
  {
      /* float: left; */ /* and probably this */
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  .dropdown .dropbtn
  {
      font-size: 20px;    
      border: none;
      outline: none;
       color: white;
       padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
  }
  .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn
  {
      background-color: #01c19e;
  }
  .dropdown-content 
  {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
  }
  .dropdown-content a
  {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .dropdown-content a:hover 
  {
      background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
  {
      display: block;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px)
  {
     .topnav a, .topnav-right
     {
       float: none;
       display: block;
     }
     .topnav-centered a
     {
       position: relative;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       transform: none;
     }
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <link href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda+One" rel = "stylesheet">
 <div class = "topnav">
    <div class = "topnav-centered">
      <img src = "AV.png">
    </div>
    <a href = "#home" class = "active"> <i class = "fa fa-fw fa-home"> </i> Home </a>
    <div class = "dropdown">
     <button class = "dropbtn"> Genre 
      <i class = "fa fa-caret-down"> </i> 
     </button>
      <div class = "dropdown-content">
         <a href = "#"> Cars </a>
         <a href = "#"> Shounen </a>
         <a href = "#"> Sports </a>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class = "topnav-right">
      <a href = "#createaccount"> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"> </i> Create Account </a>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After removing the overflow, the dropdown is fine, but the logo goes missing and if i remove the float element, the navbar gets mis aligned